# MST on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, display, splitter

I have this device [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00XXPZ3AQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XXPZ3AQ) when I connect it to Thinkpad x260 using the MiniDP, then connect into the splitter two monitors using DP cables I see no image. Any one has experience how to configure this ? The two monitors I connect are from packedpixels.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

I have now realized ArchLinux has already solved the problem (for the distro) by providing an excellent package that will solve all of your problems, just [read here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink). I am leaving the original reply as background for future users, should anyone stumble upon it.

---

The Startech MultiMonitor Splitter you bought is based upon a [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/) chip. I have bought several different verions of the splitters in question, settling eventually for [this Dell dock station](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O0M46KO).

Linux support is sketchy: it works fine on my Ubuntu and Debian laptops, but their own site states that they provide support **only** for Ubuntu. You can find the proprietary driver [here](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683482-displaylink-support-for-ubuntu-now-available), together with a list of the chips supported, basically: *DL-5xxx, DL-41xx, DL-3xxx*. I *think* your device works on a *DL-5500* (see [here](https://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/usb-3-4k-displayport-adapter~USB32DP4K) under *Technical specifications*), so you should be in luck.

The instructions on how to install this on Ubuntu are [on a separate Web page](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu) (unbelievable, isn'it?), and the instructions on how to uninstall it [on yet another page](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683699-how-to-uninstall-displaylink-ubuntu-software). Suggestions on how to port this on other Linux distros can be found [here](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/679060) (you guessed it, it is still **another** Web page). [[After buying my Dell Docking Station, it took me half a day to collect all of this information]].

The driver is made up of two parts: an OpenSource kernel module called [evdi](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi) (Extensible Virtual Display Interface) and a closed-source user-space driver called *DisplayLinkManager*, which is lodged in shared memory (*/run/shm*), both developed by DisplayLink. What I mean by proprietary is **really** proprietary: if you enable error messages, they will appear in *encrypted form*, you will have to upload them to their [forum](http://displaylink.org/forum/index.php), and they will be decoded by their own technicians. Luckily, I did not have to do this.

There is no obvious reason why you should not be able to port this to Arch, but I am not sure the proprietary driver will manage to work with Arch's cutting edge Linux kernel: I have a *4.4* on which the DisplayLink module works fine, but their Web pages make no promise as to the driver's portability to newer kernels.

How do these things work? I found out I needed a relatively powerful pc to make it work properly (an old 2008 Toshiba Portege' R600 wouldn't cut it), but it survived a powerful stress test: three screens each with a different HD movie, downloading a large file to my NAS on my LAN at 1Gb/s, and transfering a file over the Internet at 150Mb/s (what I currently have) **all simultaneously** worked perfectly. Only problem, screens freeze occasionally, and there is no way that I could find to diagnose the problem, buried as it is inside *DisplayLinkManager*, the proprietary driver.

Comment: Marked as answer. Basically from Arch point of view everything is fine. The problem is with the packedpixels.com monitors. I already wrote them, they confirmed it. If I connect to the Startech splitter different monitors they work ok. Too bad they target only Apple stuff.

Comment: The device linked in the question is a DisplayPort Multiple Stream Hub , nothing to do with DisplayLink, this answer is not correct. Note: I wrote a significant and still relevant part of the linked DisplayLink article in the Archwiki in 2013.I know quite well what DisplayLink is and what MST is.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been found out, the monitors used first were not compatible with the multiplexing hub in question. The marked answer might lead random readers into the wrong direction. **DisplayLink** and **DisplayPort MST** are entirely different technologies. DisplayLink is used when connecting monitors via **USB**. Nevertheless, the marked answer is helpful in case of issues with DisplayLink-devices (graphical USB-hubs).

*Unfortunately, I couldn't add a comment to the false answer due to unsufficient rights because of yet not enough posted answers. If I made a mistake, I'm sorry and you can delete my post. But please pass on that DisplayPort and DisplayLink should not be confused.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).